# Magento adding black background to png images

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using **Magento version 1.9.3.3** and facing the problem with few **png** images. It's adding black background automatically. Please help me to keep the transparency.

Image sample: [image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen often with Magento 1.9.3.3 or after applying patch `SUPEE 9767`. 
Please read this [Watermark get black background when transparent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177005/watermark-get-black-background-when-transparent/177402#177402.)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, uploaded the old lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php before patch and worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue with my Magento version 1.9.3.3. Below fix solve my Issue

Extend this class file `Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image`.

**Create Module :**

Crete file at `Magegeeks_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image`  with below content :

```
class Magegeeks_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image extends Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image
{

    /**
     * Validation callback for checking is file is image
     *
     * @param  string $filePath Path to temporary uploaded file
     * @return null
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     */
    public function validate($filePath)
    {
        list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filePath);
        if ($fileType) {
            if ($this->isImageType($fileType)) {
                //replace tmp image with re-sampled copy to exclude images with malicious data
                $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
                if ($image !== false) {
                    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                    imagealphablending($img, false);
                    imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                    imagesavealpha($img, true);
                    switch ($fileType) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            imagegif($img, $filePath);
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            imagepng($img, $filePath);
                            break;
                        default:
                            return;
                    }
                    imagedestroy($img);
                    imagedestroy($image);
                    return null;
                } else {
                    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
                }
            }
        }
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid MIME type.'));
    }
```

**In etc/config.xml file :**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magegeeks_Core>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Magegeeks_Core>
    </modules>
<global>
        <models>
            <sdm_core>
                <class>Magegeeks_Core_Model</class>
            </sdm_core>
            <core>
               <rewrite>
                    <file_validator_image>SDM_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image</file_validator_image>
               </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
</global>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Magegeeks_Core.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magegeeks_Core>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magegeeks_Core>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Hope this will solve your Issue.